# Why is the @RequestBody getting an object with null attributes

Tags: json, angular, rest, spring-boot

I have a springboot REST controller with the request method for a PATCH and PUT as indicated.  For some reason, the fields/attributes for @RequestBody "company" are coming in as null values.  What am I missing?

I am using angular8 on the front end and it is performing a PATCH call.

I have tried some of the other posts suggestions, but no luck.  If this is a repeated question, please point me to the answer.

```
Spring Tool Suite 4
```

Version: 4.1.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201812201347

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2018 Pivotal, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit http://spring.io/tools4

I am using pgAdmin 4.12 for postgres.

This is the call I am making from Angular:

```
    this.companyService.patch$(this.currentId, this.appMenu.currentObject).subscribe(selectedCompany => {this.appMenu.currentObject = selectedCompany});
```

This is the angular service that is called as indicated above:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Company } from '../models/company.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {
  private url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = "http://localhost:8080/niche/company";
  }

  getOne$ = (companyId: number): Observable<Company> => this.http.get<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`);

  get$ = (): Observable<Company[]> => this.http.get<Company[]>(this.url);

  post$ = (company: Company): Observable<Company> => this.http.post<Company>(this.url, { company });

  patch$ = (companyId: number, company: Company): Observable<Company> => this.http.patch<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`, { company });

  delete$ = (companyId: number): Observable<Company> => this.http.delete<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`);
}
```

Request Payload from Angular front end:

```
    {company: {createdBy: "denis", createdDate: "2019-04-14T04:00:00.000+0000", updatedBy: "denis",…}}
company: {createdBy: "denis", createdDate: "2019-04-14T04:00:00.000+0000", updatedBy: "denis",…}
companyName: "Bull Winkle"
createdBy: "denis"
createdDate: "2019-04-14T04:00:00.000+0000"
email: "bullwinkle@mail.com"
id: 2
notes: "test"
phone: "999999999"
products: []
updatedBy: "denis"
updatedDate: "2019-05-14T04:00:00.000+0000"
webSite: "bullwilkle.com"
```

This is the actual JSON:

```
{"company":{"createdBy":"denis","createdDate":"2019-04-14T04:00:00.000+0000","updatedBy":"denis","updatedDate":"2019-05-14T04:00:00.000+0000","id":2,"email":"bullwinkle@mail.com","companyName":"Bull Winkle","webSite":"bullwilkle.com","phone":"999999999","notes":"test","products":[]}}
```

The springboot backend controller:

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.ebusiness.niche.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company;
import com.ebusiness.niche.service.CompanyService;
//import com.sun.istack.internal.logging.Logger;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping( value = "/niche" )
public class CompanyController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/company"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Company>> getCompanys() {
        log.info("getCompanys(): Called...");

        List<Company> companyList = null;

        companyList = this.companyService.findAll();

        if( companyList == null || companyList.isEmpty() ) {
            log.info("getCompanys(): returned a null or empty list.");
            ResponseEntity<List<Company>> rVal = new ResponseEntity<List<Company>>(companyList, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return rVal;
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Company>>(companyList, HttpStatus.OK);       
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/company/{id}"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public ResponseEntity<Company> getCompany(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        log.info("getCompany(): Called...");
        log.info("id=" + id);

//      List<Company> companyList = null;
        Optional<Company> optcompany = null;
        Company company = null;

        optcompany = this.companyService.findById(id);

        if( optcompany == null  ) {
            log.info("getCompany(): returned a null.");
            ResponseEntity<Company> rVal = new ResponseEntity<Company>(company, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return rVal;
        } else {
            company = optcompany.get();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Company>(company, HttpStatus.OK);     
    }

    @ResponseBody
//  @RequestMapping(value = {"/company/{id}"}, headers = {
//    "content-type=application/json" }, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = { RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST })
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/company/{id}"}, method = { RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.PUT })
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})
    public ResponseEntity<Company> updateCompany(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Company company) {
        log.info("updateCompany(): Called...");
        log.info("id=" + id);

        Optional<Company> currentCompany = this.companyService.findById(id);
        Company dbCompany = null;

        if( currentCompany == null ) {
            log.error("Unable to update.  The company with id {} not found.", id);
            ResponseEntity<Company> rVal = new ResponseEntity<Company>(company, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return rVal;
        }

        dbCompany = currentCompany.get();
        dbCompany.setCompanyName(company.getCompanyName());
        dbCompany.setEmail(company.getEmail());
        dbCompany.setNotes(company.getNotes());
        dbCompany.setPhone(company.getPhone());
        dbCompany.setWebSite(company.getWebSite());

        this.companyService.update(dbCompany);

        return new ResponseEntity<Company>(dbCompany, HttpStatus.OK);       
    }

}
```

The springboot backend entity bean:

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.ebusiness.niche.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})
        }
)
public class Company extends History implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1329304564033025946L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String companyName;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String webSite;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String phone;

    @Column(length=4096)
    private String notes;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="companys")
    Set<Product> products;

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getWebSite() {
        return webSite;
    }

    public void setWebSite(String webSite) {
        this.webSite = webSite;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

This History base class entity bean:

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.ebusiness.niche.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */
//@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
public class History implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1136283585074348099L;
    private String createdBy;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Date createdDate = new Date();
    private String updatedBy;
    private Date updatedDate;
    /**
     * @return the createdBy
     */
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }
    /**
     * @param createdBy the createdBy to set
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
    /**
     * @return the createdDate
     */
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    /**
     * @param createdDate the createdDate to set
     */
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    /**
     * @return the updatedBy
     */
    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }
    /**
     * @param updatedBy the updatedBy to set
     */
    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }
    /**
     * @return the updatedDate
     */
    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }
    /**
     * @param updatedDate the updatedDate to set
     */
    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }


}
```

I edited this to add the TRACE output from the console log.  I also simplified the Company entity to not contain any dates or any other relationships to other entities, so now only strings are passed.

Here is the TRACE output:

```
   2019-09-18 15:52:19.591 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2019-09-18 15:52:19.591 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterCompletionCallback(true)
2019-09-18 15:52:19.591 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .t.i.SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl : SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl.notifySynchronizationsAfterTransactionCompletion(3)
2019-09-18 15:52:19.591 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : SessionImpl#afterTransactionCompletion(successful=true, delayed=false)
2019-09-18 15:52:19.594 DEBUG 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-09-18 15:52:19.594 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [[com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company@ddb52f3, com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company@73d5674e]]
2019-09-18 15:52:19.619 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2019-09-18 15:52:19.619 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session [f1652eeb-71a2-4776-8d94-9573336d60f3]
2019-09-18 15:52:19.619 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@6effa4c8]
2019-09-18 15:52:19.619 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2019-09-18 15:52:19.619 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Closing logical connection
2019-09-18 15:52:19.620 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2019-09-18 15:52:19.620 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Logical connection closed
2019-09-18 15:52:19.620 DEBUG 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2019-09-18 15:52:31.192 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company> com.ebusiness.niche.controller.CompanyController.updateCompany(java.lang.Long,com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company)
2019-09-18 15:52:31.264 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company> com.ebusiness.niche.controller.CompanyController.updateCompany(java.lang.Long,com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company)
2019-09-18 15:52:31.266 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : PUT "/niche/company/2", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-18 15:52:31.267 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company> com.ebusiness.niche.controller.CompanyController.updateCompany(java.lang.Long,com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company)
2019-09-18 15:52:31.268 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .i.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null, owner=null
2019-09-18 15:52:31.268 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Opened Session [740dabea-2970-4491-8ff7-d373afc649f6] at timestamp: 1568836351268
2019-09-18 15:52:31.268 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
2019-09-18 15:52:31.312 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company@46388186]
2019-09-18 15:52:31.320 TRACE 47732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: [2, com.ebusiness.niche.entity.Company@46388186]
```

Comment: Before this line `companyService.update(dbCompany);` are you getting bdCompany null? you can debug and let us know if this has not attributes as null then means when the company service updates dbCompany is doing something there.

Comment: The dbCompany gets set from the currentCompany that is returned from the find call.  This is not null.  The issue is that the "company" parameter has null attributes, which causes the constraints to fire for the null values on the update() call.  I need to know why the attributes are coming as null values for the company parameter.

Comment: The payload shows that angular is setting the attributes on the json request.

Comment: Then are you assuming that the issue in back-end? right? `Optional<Company> currentCompany = this.companyService.findById(id);` let know if this variable has some field with value(not null), if this is then in the service looks the issue.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I am not assuming anything.  I just know that the debugger reveals that the @RequestBody company has null attributes.  The currentCompany and the dbCompany are not the issue.  It is the parameter that is passed into the request.  Something is wrong from the time angular sends the request with the given payload, and the time it hits the request method for updateCompany().  The dbCompany variable will be set incorrectly as long as the "company" parameter attributes are null.

Comment: Why do not you have getters and setters on `Company` ? that is the issue, it is not being serialized.

Comment: Please @DenisMP add getters and setters for each field

Comment: The getters and setters are already there.  I did not include them in the post for brevity.

Comment: I think I may need a date deserializer.  I have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: so did you fixed by adding a format? I don't think so, since you can debug in the controller the `company` then that means deserializing is the thing.

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: could you please share your project on some repo? o maybe a basic example about them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199651/discussion-between-denismp-and-jonathan-johx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, this issue was because from `Front End application` was being sent a the JSON body as an JSON object that had nested a company. `{ company }`

```
patch$ = (companyId: number, company: Company): Observable<Company> 
          => this.http.patch<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`, { company });
```

Then when the request was coming to `Back End application` the fields values were `null` since that it was a JSON object within `company`. This was fixed by removing the brackets `{}` in order to have `company` as object.

```
patch$ = (companyId: number, company: Company): Observable<Company> 
          => this.http.patch<Company>(`${this.url}/${companyId}`, company);
```

Comment: The payload need to look like, {"createdBy":"denis","createdDate":"2019-04-14","updatedBy":"denis","updatedDate":"2019-05-14","id":2,"email":"bullwinkle@mail.com","companyName":"Bull Winkle","webSite":"bullwilkle.com","phone":"999999999","notes":"test"} and not like {"company":{"createdBy":"denis","createdDate":"2019-04-14","updatedBy":"denis","updatedDate":"2019-05-14","id":2,"email":"bullwinkle@mail.com","companyName":"Bull Winkle","webSite":"bullwilkle.com","phone":"999999999","notes":"test"}}

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

my spring boot backend code

```
@PutMapping("updateFile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateAttachment(@RequestBody Attachment attachment) {
        storageService.updateAttachment(attachment);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("file updated successfully");
    }
```

i previously tried below code and in backend `attachment` whole object happen null

```
  const message = await axiosInstance.put<string>(
        `localhost:8080/files/updateFile`,
         {attachment:attachment},
      );
```

below code worked. when passing object just pass the whole object without bracket. It will consider as data.

```
const message = await axiosInstance.put<string>(
    `localhost:8080/files/updateFile`,
      attachment,
  );
```