# Spring-boot @RequestBody JSON to object with dates deserialization example?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, serialization

Can someone provide me with a complete example of how to get a springboot PUT request to properly deserialize a `@RequestBody` object that has dates in it?  I am getting null attributes in the object and I think it is because the serialized object has util.Date's in it.

I can see the JSON payload on the front end.  It looks like this:

```
{
    "company": {
        "createdBy": "denis",
        "createdDate": "2019-04-14",
        "updatedBy": "denis",
        "updatedDate": "2019-05-14",
        "id": 2,
        "email": "bullwinkle@mail.com",
        "companyName": "Bull Winkle",
        "webSite": "bullwilkle.com",
        "phone": "999999999",
        "notes": "test",
        "products": []
    }
}
```

However, the attributes in the `@RequestBody` are all null.

I think I need to use jackson-bind, but I don't know how to implement it.

I am trying to resolve the issue at [Why is the @RequestBody getting an object with null attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979919/why-is-the-requestbody-getting-an-object-with-null-attributes) and I am suspecting the dates as the issue since the object has null attributes.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried to address the issue. This should help you out: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

Comment: This is my research at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979919/why-is-the-requestbody-getting-an-object-with-null-attributes  Please tell me how I would implement the deserialization for PUT rest call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can annotate updatedBy and updatedDate fields by this annotation to specify the format of the date that you will send it

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: I did that already, but it is not deserializing to my @RequestBody  I first posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979919/why-is-the-requestbody-getting-an-object-with-null-attributes?noredirect=1#comment102403341_57979919

Comment: Thank you Khaled.  Your answer is correct for my question and I am now using it.  My real issue for the null attributes was also answered, which had nothing to do with the dates as I thought originally.